# how can I reset focus to the active editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a vscode extension the focus is (intentionally) switched to a custom terminal, but in some cases I want the focus to return to the last active editor window. I have not found a method to achieve that reliably.

The following does not change the focus from the terminal to the code editor:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand( "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup" )
```

The only workaround that mostly works is

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand( 'workbench.action.focusNextGroup') 
vscode.commands.executeCommand( 'workbench.action.focusPreviousGroup')
```

however, in some cases the focus is not moved to the next group, but not back (possibly timing related).

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: For your workaround, those are async functions, so you need to wait for the previous one to finish before calling the next one. ```await vscode.commands.executeCommand( 'workbench.action.focusNextGroup');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand( 'workbench.action.focusPreviousGroup'); ```

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `showTextDocument()` on the active editor's document will focus it:

```
vscode.window.showTextDocument(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document)
```